# Global handlers in Ansible

Tags: ansible

Is it possible to have truly global handlers in Ansible so that I can "notify" the handler from any task of any role of any playbook?  And without explicitly importing.

I just want to define a handler once (say "restart httpd") and have it available to any "notify" directive anywhere.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You could define your handlers within your play instead of within roles.  Handlers defined in a play would be available to all tasks/roles under that play.

You are able to use import if you wanted in the handlers section too.

```
---
- hosts: all
  handlers:
  - import_tasks: global_handlers.yml
  tasks:
  - shell: echo "Hello World"
    notify: some thing from global_handlers
```

Note that you need a 'static include' (per  https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#handlers-running-operations-on-change), so `import_tasks` must be used instead of `include_tasks`:

> You cannot notify a handler that is defined inside of an include. As of Ansible 2.1, this does work, however the include must be static.

Answer (score 2):

There is at least two ways to achieve this; and it's not clear to me what the best practice is.

#### Solution 1

One [recommended practice](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse.html#re-using-tasks-as-handlers) is to create a file only for handlers, and include or import it in your playbook ([see the differences](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse.html#triggering-included-dynamic-handlers)); that way, all the roles can benefits.

For instance, let's say you have a file `myhandlers.yml` with inside one handler to restart apache, and another one to reload mysqld.

Then, in your playbook:

```yml
- name: Testing 123
  hosts: localhost
  handlers:
    - name: Here are my custom common handlers
      # You can also look at include_tasks: handlers.yml
      import_tasks: handlers.yml
  tasks:
    - command: "true"
      notify: restart-apache
    
    - command: "true"
      notify: restart-mysql
```

#### Solution 2

[Another clean approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38206472/1077650) is to create a dedicated role (`roles/myhandlers/` for instance), and make this role a depedencies for all the others roles.

```yml
dependencies:
  - myhandlers
```

More info on dependencies [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#using-role-dependencies).